# Facebook Like Box won't show in sidebar

Tags: html, css, facebook

I am trying to display a facebook like box on the sidebar of my website. Yet when I put the code in, nothing appears. I have tried moiving the code to different spots and still nothing appears. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance. Here is the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!-- Website template by freewebsitetemplates.com -->
    <html>
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Kustum Kostumes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div id="page">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="background">
            <h1 id="logo"> <a href="index.html"><img src="images/Banner1.jpg" alt="Logo" /></a> </h1>
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li class="selected">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contents">
        <div id="blog">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <div class="section">
    <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/kustumkostumes" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/kustumkostumes" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/kustumkostumes">Kustum Kostumes</a></blockquote></div>
                    <ul class="posts">
                        <li>
                            <span class="time">.</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="time"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="time"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <h5></h5>
                    <ul>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
            <h3>Welcome to Kustum Kostumes</h3>
                <p> We aim to provide high quality, handmade and crafted kostumes, props, sculptures, and artwork!<br> We put in a lot of time and effort into what we produce to make sure that not only is the client <br>happy but it looks as close as possible to the source material. </p><p>Please check out the services page to see a detailed list of what we have to offer <br>and the approximate prices for each. Please use the Gumtree links on the side <br>for what we currently have for sale. Alternatively, contact us for anything you have in mind.<br> Don't forget to like us on facebook for continual updates.    

                </p>
                <img src="images/bg-header2.jpg" alt="Img" height="325" width="547">


            </div>
            <div class="footer">


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="footer">
        <div class="background">
            <div class="body">

                <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="message" class="section">
                    <h3>Send a Message</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label>Full Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Message:</label>
                            <textarea></textarea>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="submit" value="Send">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
                <div class="section">
                    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                    <ul>

                        <li>
                            <span>Phone</span><strong>:</strong>
                            <p>
                                0450101551
                            </p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Email</span><strong>:</strong>
                            <p>
                                kustumkostumes@gmail.com        
                            </p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span><a href="http://www.facebook.com/kustumkostumes" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p id="footnote">
                    © Copyright 2017. All rights reserved. ABN 78 820 831 193
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Stylesheet

```
    /* Website template by freewebsitetemplates.com */
@font-face {
font-family: 'DaysOne-Regular';
src: url('../fonts/DaysOne-Regular.eot');
src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/DaysOne-Regular.woff') format('woff'),     url('../fonts/DaysOne-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/DaysOne-    Regular.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
body {
background: url(../images/bg-body.jpg) repeat left top;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
min-width: 960px;
margin: 0;
}
.background {
background: url(../images/bg-pattern-red.jpg) repeat left top;
}
#page {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 156px 0 0;
}
img {
border: 0;
}
/*------------------------------ SPRITES ------------------------------*/
#footer ul li a {
background: url(../images/icons.png) no-repeat;
}
#message input[type='submit'], .more {
background: url(../images/bg-buttons.png) no-repeat;
}
.more {
background-position: 0 -35px;
color: #636974;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
width: 170px;
padding: 1px 0;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.more:hover {
background-position: 0 -82px;
color: #010000;
}
/*------------------------------ HEADER ------------------------------*/
#header {
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 5px solid #c3c3c3;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
#header .background {
height: 150px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b6051c;
}
/** Logo **/
#logo {
font-family: 'DaysOne-Regular';
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 130px;
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#logo a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
/** Navigation **/
#navigation {
background: url(../images/bg-navigation.png) no-repeat;
height: 49px;
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
top: 0;
}
#navigation ul {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 1px 10px;
}
#navigation li {
float: left;
}
#navigation li a {
color: #636974;
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 47px;
width: 154px;
border-color: transparent;
border-style: none solid;
border-width: 1px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#navigation li a:hover, #navigation li.selected a {
background-color: #bebcbc;
color: #2e3a54;
border-color: #afafaf;
}
/*------------------------------ CONTENTS ------------------------------*/
#contents {
background: #fff url(../images/bg-content-bottom.png) no-repeat left bottom;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 30px;
padding: 23px 0 0;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 1px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 1px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
}
#contents h1, #contents h2, #contents h4, #contents h5, #contents h6 {
color: #2e3a54;
font-family: "DaysOne-Regular";
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0 0 18px;
}
#contents h2 {
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#contents h4 {
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 24px;
margin: 0 0 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#contents h5 {
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 24px;
margin: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#contents h5 a {
color: #940315;
text-decoration: none;
}
#contents h6 {
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 24px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#contents p {
color: #636974;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 24px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 24px;
}
#contents p a {
color: #636974;
}
#contents p a:hover {
color: #721f29;
}
#contents h5 a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
#contents .footer {
background-color: #f8f8f8;
clear: both;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 0 4px -30px;
padding: 20px 30px 0;
}
#contents .footer h6 {
float: left;
width: 210px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-right: 20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#contents .section {
width: 260px;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
#contents > div:first-child {
padding: 48px 30px 24px;
}  
.time {
color: #636974;
display: block;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 12px;
padding: 6px 0 5px;
}
/** adbox **/
#contents #adbox {
background: url(../images/bg-adbox-bottom.png) no-repeat left bottom;
padding: 0 0 19px;
position: relative;
}
#adbox > div {
background-color: #f0f0f0;
height: 390px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 1px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 1px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 1px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 1px;
padding-right: 20px;
}
#adbox > div:after {
clear:both;
content:"";
display:block;
height:1%;
line-height:0;
visibility:hidden;
}
#adbox h1 {
padding-top: 18px;
}
#adbox h4 {
font-size: 14px;
}
#adbox img {
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
}
/** Sidebar **/
#contents .sidebar {
float: left;
min-height: 490px;
width: 279px;
border-right: 1px solid #f2cc3d;
margin: -19px 40px 0 30px;
padding: 20px 0 0;
}
#contents .sidebar ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#contents .sidebar ul li {
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 24px;
margin: 0 0 24px;
}
#contents .sidebar ul span {
color: #636974;
display: block;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 12px;
padding: 6px 0 5px;
}
#contents .sidebar ul li a {
color: #636974;
text-decoration: none;
}
#contents .sidebar ul li a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
#sidebar, .highlight {
float: right;
display: inline-block;
border-left: 1px solid #f2cc3d;
margin: 0 0 24px 19px;
}
#sidebar .section {
border-top: 1px solid #f2cc3d;
padding-top: 24px;
}
#sidebar .section:first-child {
border: 0;
padding-top: 0;
}
#sidebar .section ul {
color: #636974;
font-size: x-small;
margin: 0 0 24px;
padding-left: 12px;
}
#sidebar .section ul li {
padding-left: 10px;
}
#sidebar .section ul li > a {
color: #636974;
display: block;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar .section ul li a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
/** list **/
ul.list {
list-style: none;
width: 600px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
ul.list li h5 + img {
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 6px;
}
/** Main **/
#main > ul {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
width: 580px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#main > ul li {
float: left;
width: 290px;
}
#main > ul li p b {
color: #2e3a54;
display: block;
font-family: 'DaysOne-Regular';
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
/** About **/
#contents #about {
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-top: 48px;
}
#about #main img {
margin-bottom: 18px;
}
#about .footer p {
font-size: 12px;
}
/** Services **/
#contents #services {
display: inline-block;
width: 900px;
}
#services #sidebar {
min-height: 620px;
}


/*------------------------------ FOOTER ------------------------------*/
#footer {
width: 100%;
border-top: 5px solid #c3c3c3;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
}
#footer .background {
border-top: 1px solid #b6051c;
}
#footer .body {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 40px 0 20px;
}
#footer .section {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
width: 460px;
margin: 0 10px 24px;
}
#footer h3 {
color: #fff;
font-family: 'DaysOne-Regular';
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 18px;
margin: 0 0 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#footer ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#footer ul li {
color: #b3999c;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 24px;
width: 100%;
border-top: 1px solid #8a0413;
padding: 12px 0 0;
vertical-align:top;
}
#footer ul li:first-child, #footer #message ul li {
border: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#footer ul li span {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
width: 70px;
vertical-align:top;
}
#footer ul li strong {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 6px;
vertical-align: top;
}
#footer ul li p {
float: left;
display: inline-block;
width: 370px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 12px;
}
#footer ul li a {
color: #b3999c;
display: inline-block;
height: 22px;
width: 30px;
margin: 0 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#footer ul li a.twitter {
background-position: -40px 0;
}
#footer ul li a.facebook {
background-position: -40px -32px;
}
#footer ul li a.googleplus {
background-position: -40px -64px;
}
#footer ul li a.twitter:hover {
background-position: 0 0;
}
#footer ul li a.facebook:hover {
background-position: 0 -32px;
}
#footer ul li a.googleplus:hover {
background-position: 0 -64px;
}
/** message **/
#message label {
float: left;
color: #b3999c;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 30px;
width: 96px;
margin-right: 10px;
text-align: right;
}
#message input[type='text'] {
color: #636974;
display: inline-block;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 35px;
line-height: 35px;
width: 342px;
border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
margin: 0 0 11px;
padding: 0 4px;
}
#message textarea {
color: #636974;
display: inline-block;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 95px;
line-height: 24px;
width: 342px;
border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
margin: 0 0 4px;
padding: 0 4px;
overflow: auto;
resize: none;
}
#message input[type='submit'] {
background-position: 0 0;
color: #636974;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
width: 52px;
border: 0;
margin-left: 106px;
padding: 0;
}
#message input[type='submit']:hover {
background-position: -62px 0;
color: #2e3a54;
}
#footnote {
clear: both;
color: #b75661;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Where's the code for your CSS?

Comment: The code you provided works fine for me.  It's probably something in your stylesheet.

Comment: Try making a JSFiddle and sharing the link, I bet you will get more response that way.

Comment: Edited and added the css. What's a js fiddle

Comment: Are you testing this via a local webserver, so that you call the page via `http://...` in your browser? Or are you testing this just via the local file system?

Comment: I am testing via http://www.kustumkostumes.com.au/index1.html

Comment: BUMP BUMP BUMP  BUMP